# How to create an Excel add-in that accomplishes what my formula does?

Tags: excel

I have a formula that checks whether any addresses in an address column (column A) contain certain state abbreviations or state names (listed in column B).

I have a list of 99 state abbreviations and names (Cells B1:B99) (CT and NE not included intentionally) and use this formula to reference it. A Yes is returned if any of those abbreviations or names are in an address cell (first address is in A1).

I'm fine with the formula returning false positives - I'm looking for things like "123 Main St Jacksonville FL 32034" for example, but it's fine if I get a "Yes" returned by the formula for "123 Florida Street" as well. I can filter those out manually.

Is there a way to create an Excel Add-in for all my workbooks going forward that does these checks? It would save me the time of having to add the state abbreviations/names list into a document and adjust the formula's cells it is referencing.

=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$99&"*")), "Yes", "")

Note that I have space entered before and after the 2 letter abbreviations intentionally.

AL

AK

AZ

AR

CA

CO

DC

DE

FL

GA

HI

ID

IL

IN

IA

KS

KY

LA

ME

MD

MA

MI

MN

MS

MO

MT

NV

NH

NJ

NM

NY

NC

ND

OH

OK

OR

PA

RI

SC

SD

TN

TX

UT

VT

VA

WA

WV

WI

WY

Alabama

Alaska

Arizona

Arkansas

California

Colorado

Connecticut

Delaware

Florida

Georgia

Hawaii

Idaho

Illinois

Indiana

Iowa

Kansas

Kentucky

Louisiana

Maine

Maryland

Massachusetts

Michigan

Minnesota

Mississippi

Missouri

Montana

Nebraska

Nevada

New Hampshire

New Jersey

New Mexico

New York

North Carolina

North Dakota

Ohio

Oklahoma

Oregon

Pennsylvania

Rhode Island

South Carolina

South Dakota

Tennessee

Texas

Utah

Vermont

Virginia

Washington

West Virginia

Wisconsin

Wyoming

I am not familiar with how to create any Excel add ins at all. The formula referencing the list works perfectly fine, but I am looking to save time.

Comment: First step would be to decide 1) what API you're going to use (e.g. VBA or Office Scripts). Honestly, I think you're just looking for a macro here.

Comment: You don't need an add-in, just create a macro and store it on your [personal macro workbook](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/personal-macro-workbook/). Then you can assign your macro to a keystroke and run it on whatever spreadsheet you like.